# Creating Audio wave on android using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, audio, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, waveform

I have drawn triangle and rectangle using OpenGL ES 2.0 on android. But i don't have any Idea how to make a wave using OpenGL ES 2.0.

I want to show the waveform for audio file. i have data in form of 150 points/sec waveform data displaying the mid frequencies. Each sample is an unsigned char from 0 to 255. how can i use this data to show wave on OpenGL ES 2.0.

Any suitable link will also be very helpful.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in your case would be using **shaders**.
You can take a look at the examples below to get a basic idea of how it works.

1. [Sound sinus wave](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsX3zS)
2. [Pulse waves](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tS3W3)
3. [Waves Remix](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4ljGD1)

Writing such shaders requires a base knowledge of **GLSL** language.
The Khronos Group [website](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) contains all the needed information to get you started.

Also you could check out the following useful links:

- [Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) - a good starting point for beginners.
- [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/new) - useful to practice writing your own shaders.

Comment: Thanks. Shaders are best if a person want moving wave. But, this is not my requirement. I want a Static wave like a timeline in a Horizontal Scroll View. which will move when audio is playing.